# jquery function undefined for IE9

Tags: jquery, function, internet-explorer-9, undefined

Iam new @ jquery - Thats working for almost all versions of IE except IE9 it says "Error: 'f' is undefined" i didnt know why ?? and if its not recommended to giving function name like that way then what should i do ?

```
$(document).ready(function f(txtName) 

    {
    $("#ctl00_Content_chkBox" + txtName).click(function () 
       {
         var thisCheck = $(this);
         if  (thisCheck.is(':checked')) 
           {
             var myDate = new Date();
             var displayDate = 
                 (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (myDate.getDate()) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
             $(this).next(".textbox1").val(displayDate);
           }
       });
    });

<input type="checkbox" ID="chkBoxName" runat="server"   onclick="f('Name');" />

<asp:TextBox CssClass="textbox1" PreValue="" runat="Server" ID="txt_comp_name_date_v" Required="false" Enabled="False"  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only use `$(document).ready()` with code that you want to run at initialization time.  You do not use it for named functions that you want to run later.  You look like you were trying to do some of both with the same code.

I would suggest changing your code like this.  I've removed the name on the function and removed the `onclick=f()` from your HTML that referred to it as you don't need either.  Now, there is a click handler that is run in the `$(document).ready()` that hooks up the click handler function for you (no need for `onclick="f()"` any more).  The code for the click handler then carries out the rest of your work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#chkBoxName").click(function () {
     var thisCheck = $(this);
     if  (thisCheck.is(':checked')) {
       var myDate = new Date();
       var displayDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (myDate.getDate()) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
       thisCheck.next(".textbox1").val(displayDate);
     }
   });
});

<input type="checkbox" ID="chkBoxName" runat="server" />

<asp:TextBox CssClass="textbox1" PreValue="" runat="Server" ID="txt_comp_name_date_v" Required="false" Enabled="False"  />
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9y7sC/.

You should be very careful with this part of the code `thisCheck.next(".textbox1")` because that is very picky about finding your text field.  If you put any intervening HTML tag in between the two, it won't work - it has to be the very next HTML tag and it has to have the right class.

If you have a lot of checkboxes next to text fields and you want them all to get this function, then just give them all the same class name and refer to that class in the jQuery code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".dateCheckbox").click(function () {
     var thisCheck = $(this);
     if  (thisCheck.is(':checked')) {
       var myDate = new Date();
       var displayDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (myDate.getDate()) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
       thisCheck.next(".textbox1").val(displayDate);
     }
   });
});

<input type="checkbox" class="dateCheckbox" runat="server" />

<asp:TextBox CssClass="textbox1" PreValue="" runat="Server" ID="txt_comp_name_date_v" Required="false" Enabled="False"  />
```

Here's an example of multiple checkboxes working off the one piece of code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/twu5n/

Comment: Wish i can vote up but i dont have 15 rep yet O.o thanks alot tho for Info :)

Comment: Are you sure the icktoofay solution is really how you want your UI to work?  Two checkboxes have to get checked before the date is entered in the textbox and if someone clicks on the second one before the first one, then nothing happens?

Comment: why two checkboxes have to get checked ? i have only 1 checkbox next to textbox and in the form its repeated with diffrent ids thats why iam passing the name of each checkbox in the parameter

Comment: The way the code works in your original code and in icktoofay's code is the `"#ctl00_Content_chkBox" + txtName` checkbox initially has no click handler.  When the `ID="chkBoxName"` checkbox is clicked, it installs a click handler for `"#ctl00_Content_chkBox" + txtName` and does nothing more until the `"#ctl00_Content_chkBox" + txtName` itself is clicked.  The way my code works, the click handler is installed when the page loads for the `ID="chkBoxName"` checkbox and the first time it's clicked, it puts a date into the textbox.

Comment: aww sry i should have said that some how all the checkboxes has that added to its Id "ctl00_Content_" so its rendered with that name in IE "ctl00_Content_chkBoxName" so its not another checkbox

so when i passed f('Name') is to complete the ID coz all checkboxes have that ID "ctl00_Content_chkBox"

Comment: If they are the same checkbox, all the first click will do is call `f('Name')` and all that function will do is install the second JQuery-based click handler.  Either way, it doesn't make sense to me.  Please study the code I have and compare it.  I don't care which one you choose, but I'm not sure you understand what both solutions do and which one actually suits your purpose better.

Comment: i understand ur code correctly i just dont know how to pass another id with ur code way i have like 10 checkboxes with diffrenet ID names ex: "ctl00_Content_chkBoxName" and "ctl00_Content_chkBoxAddress" and thanks alot for help i know u just want me to get it right :) please advice if u got what i mean

Comment: I added another example to the end of my answer that shows you how to do it if you have lots of checkbox/textfield pairs that you want to have the same functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a named function expression to `$(document).ready`. Previous versions of Internet Explorer had a bug which exposed the function into the surrounding scope. It appears Internet Explorer 9 has fixed this bug that you were relying on. Use a function declaration rather than a named function expression by not passing it to `$(document).ready`:

```
function f(txtName) {
    $("#ctl00_Content_chkBox" + txtName).click(function () {
        var thisCheck = $(this);
        if (thisCheck.is(':checked')) {
            var myDate = new Date();
            var displayDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (myDate.getDate()) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
            $(this).next(".textbox1").val(displayDate);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense to me.  When a checkbox is clicked, it installs a click handler on some other checkbox and that checkbox doesn't have an event handler until the first checkbox is clicked.  So, to get the date to go into a field, two checkboxes have to be checked?  Is that really how the UI is supposed to work?

Comment: i face a problem here when i check the checkbox it dont run the job instantly its like i have to check to call the function then uncheck and check again to do the job !!